# Exchange of two elements of a doubly linked list C#

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list, compare-and-swap

How can I swap two elements of a two-linked list(by switching links)? I realized that I need to consider four cases: change with the first / last elements, change neighboring elements, and all other cases.
The cell structure is as follows:

```
public class Item<T>
{
    private T _Data;
    private Item<T> _Next;
    private Item<T> _Prev;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _Data; }
        set { this._Data = value; }
    }
    public Item(T Data)
    {
        this._Data = Data;
    }
    public Item()
    {
        this._Data = default;
    }
    public Item<T> Next
    {
        get { return this._Next; }
        set { this._Next = value; }
    }
    public Item<T> Prev
    {
        get { return this._Prev; }
        set { this._Prev = value; }
    }
}
```

This is an implementation attempt. What's wrong?(Here I also do insert sort, but it all depends on the exchange of two elements)

```
    public override D_List<T> Sorting(D_List<T> a)
    {
        for (int top = 1; top < a.Count; top++)
        {
            int k = top;
            while (k > 0 && a[k-1] > a[k])
            {
                k--;
            }

            if (k == 0)
            {
                a[top].Prev.Next = a[top].Next;
                a[top].Next.Prev = a[top].Prev;
                a[top].Next = a[k];
                a[top].Prev = null;
                a[k].Prev = a[top];
            }
            else if(k == a.Count - 2)
            {
                a[k].Prev.Next = a[top];
                a[top].Prev = a[k].Prev;
                a[k].Next = null;
                a[k].Prev = a[top];
            }
            else if(k+1 == top)//стоят подряд
            {
                a[k].Prev.Next = a[top];
                a[top].Prev = a[k].Prev;
                a[k].Next = a[top].Next;
                a[top].Next = a[k];
                a[k].Next.Prev = a[k];
            }
            else
            {
                a[k].Prev = a[top];
                a[top].Prev.Next = a[top].Next;
                a[top].Next.Prev = a[top].Prev;
                a[top].Prev = a[k].Prev;
                a[top].Next = a[k];
                a[top].Next.Prev = a[top];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: If you add dummy head/tail elements, all the cases will condense into a single one, which will dramatically simplify your code

Comment: If  I am not wrong, your question title is slightly different than your explanation. in your explanation Two-LinkedList?? you mean doubly-linked list right?

Comment: No, i'm sorry, it's doubly linked list

Comment: It looks like you should be able to swap the `Value` property values. Unless you're exposing `Item<T>` to the consumer (and you probably shouldn't) and you update any cached values you may have, it doesn't matter which instance holds the value. Demote `Item<T>` from `public` to be safe.